# onclick html attribute isn't doing anything

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a modal dialog that is generated with createTemplateFromFile and uses scriptlets to access functions in my script files. I'm trying to create a button in the dialog that will run a function hosted in a script tag in the HTML template using the onclick html attribute. The problem is I can't get it to do anything... at all.

At this point, the function I'm trying to trigger is only written to log "it worked!" to the console so it's not complicated. That's not triggering so I don't think it's registering the event at all.

```
function example() {
    console.log("click counted");
}

<? var functions = triggerIds(); ?>

<? for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) { ?>
  <div>
    <div onclick="example()" name="<?= functions[i] ?>">
       <span><?= functions[i] ?></span>
       <span class="fa-stack fa-2x" >
         <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-trash fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
<? } ?>
```

I left the scriptlet part on the div because I suspect the fact that this is generated and then the dialog is created might be affecting it but it should still call the function on a click, even if the tag is generated before the function is.

Comment: Seems to work for me in a codepen. Where are you declaring function. Are you importing the script file correctly? Can you reproduce the error in a minimal reproducible example.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You will be having any console error before `function example() {}` check script files @jeff

Comment: @NabeelMehmood thanks for your response :). I'll look into minimal reproducible examples. Unless I'm misunderstanding, I'm not importing a script file at all. the function is referenced in a script tag at the top of the HTML file. Also, this is a Google Apps Script so I don't think importing script files is how it generally works, you have to reference them with scriptlets

Comment: @NijinKoderi I"m not sure I follow. Can you elaborate?

Comment: `At this point, the function I'm trying to trigger is only written to log "it worked!" to the console so it's not complicated` You're looking at the browser dev console right? Also Your second ``span`` is not closed.

Comment: @TheMaster I can't believe it... turns out in the actual code (as opposed to above) I didn't close the second span and BAM, it's working. Embarrassing mistake, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to trigger a click event, you need to have a clickable text.
2. `name=<?=functions[i] ?>` goes without quotes, since it is a variable name and not a text string.
3. You need to define `functions[i]` before you can use it

### Sample:

```
  <?var functions=[];?>
  <?for(var i=0; i<10;i++){?>
  <?functions[i]=i ?>
       <div onclick="example()" name=<?=functions[i]?>> 
         <?=functions[i]?> 
       </div>
  <?}?>
```

> Mind the difference between `<?` and `<?=` [scriplets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: Hey @ziganotschka, thanks for responding :) So I trimmed a lot of the elements so that only the relevant parts showed but there are additional HTML elements within the div (I notice I didn't close it though). Also, name is an HTML attribute so that does need to be in quotes, right? Finally, I do define functions, I just didn't include it in my sample. The core of it is pulled from a separate script file in Google Scripts to generate the HTML

Comment: You do need quotes if you want to assign to name the evaluated content of functions[i], rather than a string "<?=functions[i]?>". Where do you define `functions`? Should be within the scriptlets in the HTML part of the code, such as in my sample. And once again, you need to insert a text or variable between the <div></div> tags, on which you click to trigger the click event. If my code above is not what you need - if you provide your code including the definition of  `functions` I can have a look at it.

Comment: I updated the code to show you more. There is clickable text but it's generated by a scriptlet like you have in your sample